# how to add ith item from one List to another

Tags: c#

Suppose I have 2 lists:

```
List<string> CharactersInStringEnteredByUser = new List<string>();
List<string> CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString = new List<string>();

while (CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Count < 25)
{
    CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Add(????);
}
```

I want to add i<sup>th</sup>  item from `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString` to `CharactersInStringEnteredByUser`.

**Update: **

Let me clarify my question.

I want to check `if CharactersInStringEnteredByUser < 25` ? If so then add first item from `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString`.

Now again check `if CharactersInStringEnteredByUser < 25` ? If so then add second item from `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString`.

And so on......

Comment: `while (CharactersInStringEnteredByUser < 25)`? does it even compile?? what are you trying to do..?

Comment: The code you've posted makes no sense at all (how do you compare a list to `25`?). Please clarify your question and post code that will compile.

Comment: @Sachin I am sorry, its .Count

Comment: Probably *i* th, or *n* th.

Comment: @DanielMann yes you are correct.

Comment: We understand that `i` is a variable, but please explain what it represents. Your code has no reference to `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> CharactersInStringEnteredByUser = new List<string>();
List<string> CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString = new List<string>();

int i = 0;
while (CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Count < 25)
{
    CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Add(CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You should also verify that `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString` has enough items.
I would add a check in the loop's body.

The final code can be:

```
int i = 0;
while (CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Count < 25)
{
    if (i >= CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString.Count)
        break;

    CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Add(CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify my question. I want to check if `CharactersInStringEnteredByUser < 25`? If so then add first item from `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString`. Now again check if `CharactersInStringEnteredByUser < 25`? If so then add second item from `CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString`. And so on......

Comment: Thanks, thats a much cleaner and better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to take first 25 values from first list and save them into second. So you can do this

```
CharactersInStringEnteredByUser = CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString.Take(25).ToList();
```

If your list may be already filled (as you are checking its count) then you can do this.

```
int count = CharactersInStringEnteredByUser.Count;
if(count < 25)
  CharactersInStringEnteredByUser = CharactersInAutomaticallyGeneratedString.Take(25-count).ToList();
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of yours. No need for duplicates. Not entirely sure why this isn't *the* answer. -.-